# Android inscribed circle

Tags: java, android, math, geometry, android-linearlayout

I am currently working on Code based drawables in Android but ran into a little bump, I have a rectangular LinearLayout that I want to set it's drawable to a circle I have reasons for doing this in code so please do not recommend xml, I did some searching on Google and was only really able to come up with the opposite an inscribed rectangle in circle and that is not what I need.

So let's say I have a rectangle of 80 wide and 120 in length(these are random guesses, and need to be able to change) what would be the formula I need to use to determine the largest circle I can create in this rectangle and when I say circle let me be more specific I do not want a oval I want a full circle.

So this question is simply what would be the proper formula needed for this. Thank you for your time =)

Comment: For clarification when I say how large of a circle, I mean the diameter of the circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int Radius = Math.min( width, height ) / 2;

That is the largest radius circle that can fit in the rectangle

Comment: Might want to also subtract the stroke width, just so that it's drawn completely inside the box.

Comment: Ok awesome I just posted my thoughts before I saw yours, my Internet was flapping. I gave u credit though.  Thank you very much for your time =)

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm back again and feel slightly stupid on this one,

The answer came to me during good old shower time (doesn't it always).  I was thinking about my problem in the 3d senses something I regretfully did not do before I posted on here.  It occurred to me that if I want to make a for lack of better term a perfect circle that the diameter of this circle would always be constricted by the smaller side of the rectangle and then you can account for that to center the circle.

So in my scenario my circle with be 80 in diameter because it would be restricted by the width of the rectangle. Sorry for wasting your time have a good day =)